# Should I ask a question on SO that's essentially "Where's this at?"

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I'm looking for a pretty difficult to search for resource (in this case, a "machine parsable dictionary" which google answers by showing me "machine parsable" definitions from decidedly un-machine parsable dictionary websites)

Are questions like this good to ask on Stack Overflow, or not?

Comment: No, you can't ask us to find things on the internet for you.

Comment: Well, on softwarerecs.se you can ask to find a piece of software matching certain requirements. It *might* be possible to make this question ontopic there, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you ask such a question you might get some answers with links.

After a year or two most of those links will likely be dead. This means that the question and its answers are not generally long-term useful and that's what we're trying to achieve here.

Spammers also like questions with lots of answers that are just links as they can hide other answers that are just links in that whole mess.

Hence we don't allow questions about "can you find this on the internet for me" in the first place. Most sites have something like this as one of the off-topic reasons...

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.